# Required_once file not routing correctly

Tags: php, apache, include, require-once

I am attempting to include a file, which I have done so successfully on the exact page which I am having issues now. For some reason the following calls are not working. I have tried all three methods.

```
require_once ("required_files/page-count.php");
require_once 'required_files/page-count.php';
include_once("required_files/page-count.php");
```

Initially I named the folder `php` instead of `required_files` and I received error messages, so I changed it thinking that php may have been a restricted folder name. Now since I have changed it, it appears it is still searching for the previous name I had, but it is no where within my code.

The errors:

> Warning: require_once(php/page-count): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home4/public_html/account/required_files/page-count.php on line 40
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'php/page-count' (include_path='.:/opt/php55/lib/php') in /home4/public_html/account/required_files/page-count.php on line 40

The home files is the file I am trying to include the file `page-count.php` file within.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on and why this won't work?

[image]

In `required_files` folder:

[image]

Comment: Is the folder listing you're showing for `account` or `public_html`?

Comment: @wogsland It is for `account`.

Comment: I know it appears I am still calling for `php/post-count.php`, but I am not and that is why I am so confused.

Comment: What's on line 40 of `page-count.php`?

Comment: @wogsland Right now it is a commented out line of code. Not sure why it is reading it. `//require_once ("required_files/page-count.php");`. The line I have uncommented is `include_once("required_files/page-count.php");` ....... I do not have the `php/post-count.php` anywhere on the page, not even commented out.

Comment: @wogsland It appears that whenever I do `include_once("required_files/page-count");` (leave out the .php) the page will load, but leave me with a warning that the page doesn't exist. Why do you think whenever I put php in the link it kills it off? I have other instances of `.php` and it works, such as: `require_once("fixDate.php");`

Answer (score 0):

The /opt/php55/lib/php is the default path. It will try there if it can't find it anywhere else.

I would echo a test.php like this:

This will tell you if it's /home4/publc_html/ or /home4/public_html/account as your root directory.

It is good form to use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] because your host may move you to a new server with a different home folder. This way it will always resolve to the correct place.

Comment: <?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; ?>  in a test.php